# Error dumping tombstone

Tags: android, debugging, tombstone

I'm using debugger to process android dump, but I'm getting some errors. What's the problem?

> shell@K80M:/ $ debuggerd 2974 Sending request to dump task 2974. Error
>   dumping tombstone.

Comment: Please add some details to your question - what are you doing exactly to get this error?

Comment: I use adb in android sdk in windows, 

I typed command , adb shell,
debuggerd pid, 
then it shows "Sending request to dump task 2974. Error dumping tombstone".